# Django Forms replace integer value with String Value

Tags: django-forms

I have these choice types on my model:

```
AVAILABLE = [
  (7, _("7 AM")),
  (8, _("8 AM")),
  (9, _("9 AM")),
  (10, _("10 AM")),
  (11, _("11 AM")),
  (12, _("Noon")),
  (13, _("1 PM")),
  (14, _("2 PM")),
  (15, _("3 PM")),
  (16, _("4 PM")),
  (17, _("5 PM")),
  (18, _("6 PM")),
  (19, _("7 PM")),
]
```

I rendered my form using the following:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  <select class="chosen-select" id="id_mon_start" name="mon_start">
    <option selected="selected">{{availability_hours.mon_start }}  </option>
      {% for choice in form.fields.mon_start.choices %}
        <option value="{{ choice.0 }}">{{choice.1}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <div class="error-block">{{ form.mon_start.errors }}</div>
</div>
```

My form works and updates as required with all the correct values, I would like to show the string value of my AVAILABLE choices instead of the integer on my option selected="selected" ,I'm having no look with tips I've googled to do this. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) is what you are looking for:

```
<option selected="selected">{{ availability_hours.get_mon_start_display }}  </option>
```